# Construct regex to allow just one '+"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on following regex where I want my regex to return true only if there is one '+' in the beginning,not after any other character. currently it returns true for many plus like this :
+61+282827272, but valid input is +61262828282.

```
^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([1-9][0-9]{7,15})$
```

However this string can begin without + as well like : 00123456789 or 123456789

Comment: Which is it? `java` or `javascript`?

Comment: Why not simply count the number of `+`-characters in your string using `IEnumerable.Count`?

Comment: `java`, `javascript` and `c#`? You expect it to work on all those languages?

Comment: or if it's javascript you use `var m = num.match(/\+/); m && m.length == 1`

Comment: @Turing : Javascript .But I tagged other language to reach out to more users.As usually I think regex are more or less same for each language.

Comment: @Kumar That's not how this site works and that's seriously against the rules. Please don't do that again.

Comment: "more or less the same" is not "exactly the same" though, stick to the language you are using. :)

Comment: what about `^\+?\d+$`

Comment: @Camilo: Thanks for clarifying the rules.I will pay attention to that.

Comment: Try Regex: `^\+?\d+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches `+` in the middle of the string because you've got an un-closed `[character class]` :

```
^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([1-9][0-9]{7,15})$
   ^^^^^^^^
```

Not sure what you wanted to write, but this is a character class that contains the character 0, `|`, `+`, `[` and the digits from 0 to 9 and can be repeated up to five times, which is why `+` in the first five characters will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with this: `^\+.*?\+.*$`
If this is true, then there is a + in the middle of your string